# How to handle nested object in Entities that have no other relation

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Consider the following class:

```
public class Country{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Coordinate Coordinate {get;set;}
}
public class Coordinate{
   public Latitude {get;set;}
   public Longitude {get;set;}
}
```

Now, when I create a migration, it creates two tables: `Country` and `Coordinate` with a mapping between the two tables.

```
Table: Country
[id, name, coordinateId]

Table: Coordinate
[id, latitude, longitude]
```

This feels shady, as the coordinate doesn't have a relation to anything else. It could also be stored in the same table.

I feel like the better way is to have 1 table `[Country]` with all the fields:

```
Table: Country
[id, name, coordinate_latitude, coordinate_longitude]
```

Is it acceptable in EF that there are a lot of tables for nested objects that are filled with data only used by its main parent? Or is there a way to 'flatten' the objects that is more efficient?

Comment: What EFCore do you use?

Comment: @DmitriBodiu 3.1.20

Comment: Look at my answer, that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects

There is an example how to set up value objects as columns in the main table:

orderConfiguration.OwnsOne(p => p.Address)
.Property(p=>p.Street).HasColumnName("ShippingStreet");

orderConfiguration.OwnsOne(p => p.Address)
.Property(p=>p.City).HasColumnName("ShippingCity");

Comment: Thank you, that works. So the term to google for is "Owned Entity".

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [SqlGeography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography?view=sql-dacfx-150)

```cs
public class Country{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public SqlGeography Coords {get;set;}
}
```

Else you can flatten the class anyway.

```cs
public class Country{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public double Latitude {get;set;}
   public double Longitude {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The coordinate was an example for a nested object. It doesnt have to be a coordinate.

Comment: Ok, this confused me. So @DmitriBodiu answer is the best.